# write to current working path to file using command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How to write current directory path to file(text file or bat file) using windows command line(cmd) ?

Answer (score 1):

The `cd` command, without any arguments, will print the current directory.

You can pipe that to a file: `cd > Filename`

Comment: copy con abc.txt                                               cd>filename                                                         ^Z                                                                  not worked

Comment: That's a _command_.  You need to execute it, not print it.    Read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx

Comment: @SLakes what happen if you add echo infront of the command. there is a echo exist in default. iwant to ignore that echo,

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying.  You may be looking for the `@` character.